# label length of state transition in Enterprise Architecture

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm very new to Enterprise Architecture, In a state machine i tried to give the name for a transition. but it takes only 255 characters. Is there any way to give name having more than 255 characters?

Comment: Why do you need a name that long? Could some of the name go in the Notes field?

Comment: If a comment / answer helped you, please upvote and / or accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot extend the length of the name field (possibly you may hack yourself through using EA's automation interface, but even then it's probably not worth the effort).
For modeling elements, you can add a tagged value to the element and assign it the MEMO data type but that can be [a bit complicated](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1363788841/0#0). Then you can set the diagram to display tagged values. So the solution suggested by @chimp is probably better.